# Comparing two timestamp

Tags: c++

I coded the following function which is very simple. It seems not to work when I compare two CTime. I really don't know what is wrong, may you help me please?

```
bool operator<(CTime second)
{
if (year<second.getYear())
  return true;
if (year>second.getYear())
  return false;
if (year<second.getMonth())
  return true;
If (year>second.getMonth())
  return false;
if (year<second.getDay())
  return true;
if (year>second.getDay())
  return false;
if (year<second.getHour())
  return true;
if (year>second.getHour())
  return false;
if (year<second.getMin())
  return true;
if (year>second.getMin())
  return false;
if (year<second.getSec())
  return true;
if (year>second.getSec())
  return false;
return false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you aware that `CTime` already has an `operator<`?

Comment: "the following function which is very simple": Kindly, I presume that this is totally subjective?

Comment: I am trying to reimplement it.

Comment: @bandera dont. But if you must, there are open source implementations that you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing with `year` for all the fields.

Instead of

```
if (year<second.getMonth())
  return true;
```

You need

```
if (this->getMonth()<second.getMonth())
  return true;
```

Similarly for the other fields.

**Update**

You can make the code a bit less verbose by replacing the lines:

```
if (year<second.getYear())
  return true;
if (year>second.getYear())
  return false;
```

with

```
if (year != second.getYear())
  return (year < second.getYear());
```

Similarly for the other fields.

Comment: Thank you. I realize it is stupid.

Comment: @bandera, you are welcome. Don't feel too bad. Most of us have been through that phase.